# Get child div of existing div using anchors next element without ID or class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see below `$(nextDiv + ' > div').eq(i).fadeIn('slow');` does not work as it seems to be malformed. `nextDiv` is on inspection the div below the anchor, how do I achieve getting the two divs that sit inside it?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn2" onclick="subClick(this)">Sub Click</a>
<div>
    <div>I want this to fade in on the click</div>
    <div>Followed by this etc.</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function subClick(myAnchor)
{
    var nextDiv = $(myAnchor).next();
    function showDiv(i) {
        if (i > 2) return;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(nextDiv + ' > div').eq(i).fadeIn('slow');
            showDiv(++i);
        }, 50);
    }
    showDiv(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a string with jQuery, that won't provide a valid selector. The concatenation would provide something like `"[object Object] > div"` which doesn't select any elements in your code.

Instead, get the `div` children using [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method on the jQuery `nextDiv` object.

```
nextDiv.children('div').eq(i).fadeIn('slow');
```

---

If there are only two divs then you can reduce the code using [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method.

```js
function subClick(myAnchor) {
  var nextDivs = $(myAnchor).next().children();
  // if you want to do the animation after the first then
  // use the below code, where second animation initializing within 
  // the first animation success callback, which also provides a 50ms          
  // delay for second animation(avoid .delay(50) if you dont nedd that delay)
  
  //  nextDivs.eq(0).fadeIn('slow', function() {
  //    nextDivs.eq(1).delay(50).fadeIn('slow');
  //  });

  
  // in case you just want to provide a 50ms delay
  // between animation then use, your code does this
  nextDivs.eq(0).fadeIn('slow');
  nextDivs.eq(1).delay(50).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var nextDiv = $(myAnchor).next();` then `nextDiv` is an object not a selector. If you want to access its `div` children use this:

```
nextDiv.children('div').eq(i).fadeIn('slow');
```